# magit-status in a new frame and delete frame on exit

Tags: emacs, magit

I want to create a keybinding to open the magit-status buffer in a new frame as the only window and once the magit-status buffer is closed(q) then the frame should also close.

The following keybinding works but it leaves the frame open.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>")
        '(lambda ()
           (interactive)
           (select-frame (make-frame-command))
           (magit-status)
           (delete-other-windows)))
```

Magit version

```
(magit-version)
Magit 20180219.1545, Git 2.1.4, Emacs 24.4.1, gnu/linux
```

Comment: Bind q in the magit map to delete frame

Answer (score 3):

Simply bind `q` in the `magit-mode-map` to `delete-frame`

```
(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "q") 'delete-frame)
```